# az cmd "account clear" fails after "az storage blob upload-batch"

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm using the azure cli in my tfs release pipeline to upload the artifacts of the preceeding build pipeline to an azure blob storage.

The used script is like follows:

```
az storage blob upload-batch --account-key $(Storage.Key) --account-name $(Storage.AccountName) -d $(Storage.Container)/$(Storage.SubFolder) -s $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myartefact/dist
```

The file upload works fine. But after having finished it obviously tries to perform an `account clear` command which fails:

> 2020-06-15T11:28:57.2682530Z
> Finished[#############################################################]
> 100.0000%
>
> 2020-06-15T11:28:57.4557138Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account clear"
>
> 2020-06-15T11:28:59.7995176Z ##[error]Script failed with error: Error:
> D:\w_temp\azureclitaskscript1592220526658.bat failed with return
> code: 0
>
> 2020-06-15T11:28:59.7995176Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy Files
> to Blob Storage

I don't know why this command is executed and I don't know why it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running the Azure CLI task with the `Fail on Standard Error` option unchecked. This could be the script is writing some message to `stderr` stream .

[image]

You can refer to this [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6554) with similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Yes, I already did that - but isn't it rather a hacky workaround than a solution for the issue?

Comment: As advice: To avoid the failure, you might need to redirect the standard error stream to standard output for executing the command .